# Node.js/express. Как принять файл отправленный не из html-формы?

Tags: node.js, файлы, fileupload, upload, express

Как используя модуль express принять (вытащить из request) файл, отправленный не из html-формы, А из вручную сформированного POST-запроса ??

Например если такой запрос:

> POST http://localhost:3000/photos
>
> Content-Type: image/png
>
> Filename: C:\Users\User\Desktop\resize.png

или если через Curl такой:

> curl -X POST -F "images_file=@resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos
>
> curl -X POST -T "resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos

Вот, как вытащить и обработать файл этот??

Comment: И чем это отличается от html-формы?

Comment: Почитайте что такое http-протокол, спецификацию протокола. И браузер и curl одинаково используют http, быть может лишь с разницей что не все поля http одинаково заполнены (о чём можно говорить при понимании http).

Comment: да не могу я используя модуль express вытащить (получить) файл этот! из POST-запросов которые написал выше. Приведите пример обработки этих запросов тогда..

Comment: Ха! Я вставил такой модульчик (как ниже) в проектик и попробовал вот этим курлом - `curl -X POST -T "resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos` - отправить файл (никогда так не делал) - и работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот так и сохранить:

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {

  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('..здесь абсолютный путь до файла/file.png');

  req.pipe(writeStream);

  req.on('end', function () {
    res.end();
  });

  writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

};
```

Comment: хорошо) Как принять файл? Вот отправил я эти пост-запросы, 
    curl -X POST -F "images_file=@resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos
    curl -X POST -T "resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos             Есть эта функция function(req, res) Вот как мне из этого req вытащить файл? чтобы потом сохранить..

Comment: Да у меня пусто в req.body .. ниче нету..  я не могу понять где файл то, как его из этих запросов 
    curl -X POST -F "images_file=@resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos
    curl -X POST -T "resize.png" http://localhost:3000/photos
 получить

Comment: Щас я проверю.. а то вот этот момент как раз понять не могу..